# Record filtration issue

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have 2 tables in database : 1. Agents table & 2. UserPermissions table

Table 1 Agents contains list of Agents as given below; here CompanyID & AgentID are unique values.

```
AgentID  AgentCode CompanyID RailEnabled  
1             A1        1          1  
2             A2        2          0  
3             A3        3          1  
4             A4        4          0
```

Table 2 UserPermissions table contains list of all users who are coming under a particular agent. And there are 2 fields ModuleCode whose values are like 'RAL' for Rail in short and Enabled fields.

```
UserID UserName ModuleCode Enabled CompanyID

1   U1  RAL 1   1  
2   U2  RAL 0   1  
3   U3  RAL 1   1  
13  U4  BUS 1   1  
4   U1  RAL 0   2  
5   U2  RAL 0   2  
6   U3  RAL 0   2  
14  U4  HTL 1   2  
7   U1  RAL 0   3  
8   U2  RAL 0   3  
9   U3  RAL 0   3  
15  U4  FLT 1   3  
10  U1  RAL 0   4  
11  U2  RAL 0   4  
12  U3  RAL 0   4  
16  U4  BUS 1   4
```

Now I need to filter out only the Agents for which RailEnabled is true but none of the users of that Agent is not enabled for Rail service(Module code: RAL).

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please edit your post to tag it with the RDBMS you're using. Also, provide SQL you've written to attempt what you're trying to do. Gotta show what you've tried first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NOT EXISTS.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5fa60/1)

```
select * from agents a
where railenabled = 1     --assuming 1 means enabled
and not exists (select 1  --not exists to remove all agents whose users have RAL enabled
                from userpermissions b
                where a.companyid = b.companyid
                and b.modulecode = 'RAL'
                and b.enabled = 1
                );
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I am new to the use of Exist. When we use Exist When a subquery is introduced with the keyword EXISTS, the subquery functions as an existence test. The WHERE clause of the outer query tests whether the rows that are returned by the subquery exist. The subquery does not actually produce any data; it returns a value of TRUE or FALSE(MSDN)